# My search method doen't work with number even with ToString()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net, search-form

As you can see, I have a method to retrieve fields from my table. In my view, I do the search in two textbox.

**ClientID** is a *string*, so no problem it works. But **OrderId** is an *Int*, so I use ToString() but it still don't work.

Am I wrong in the way I wrote my second IF condition for OrderId ? Thanks for your help

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchString, string searchOrder)
{  
    var user = from m in db.Order   
               select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        user = user.Where(s => s.Order.ClientID.Contains(searchString));
    }         

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchOrder))
    {
        user = user.Where(c => c.Order.OrderId.ToString().Contains(searchOrder));
    }

    return this.View("Order", "PrintView", user);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search with number, change the method in question to the following :

```
 public ActionResult PrintOrders(string searchString, int searchOrder = 0)
    {
        var user = from m in db.OrderDetails   
                   select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            user = user.Where(s => s.Order.ClientID.Contains(searchString));               
        }

        if (searchOrder > 0)
        {
            user = user.Where(c => c.Order.OrderId == searchOrder);               
        }

        return this.ViewPdf("Order", "PrintView", user);
    }
```

Another method is :

```
    public ActionResult PrintOrders(string searchString, string searchOrder)
    { 
        var user = from m in db.OrderDetails   
                   select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            user = user.Where(s => s.Order.ClientID.Contains(searchString));               
        }

        int tmp = Int32.Parse(searchOrder);

        if (tmp != 0)
        {
            user = user.Where(c => c.Order.OrderId == tmp);
        }

        return this.ViewPdf("Order", "PrintView", user);
    }
```

And the view looks like that :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PrintOrders", "Historic", FormMethod.Get, new { target = "_blank" }))
{

   Search by Client ID : @Html.TextBox("searchString")

   Search by Order ID : @Html.TextBox("searchOrder")

  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should be parsing `searchOrder` to an integer, then using:

```
user = user.Where(c => c.Order.OrderId == targetOrderId);
```

Aside from anything else, would you *really* want a `searchOrder` of "15" to match order 2150? That sounds unlikely to be useful.

Comment: You're right, is not too useful, how can I do to change it in your opinion ? In the meantime, the following code is what you have told me to do ?   `int targetOrderId= Int32.Parse(searchOrder)` and then  `user = user.Where ...`

Comment: @Alternative: Yes, although consider whether you want to allow group separators when parsing, etc. (There are cultural issues when parsing, basically.) The change I've made will only match the *exact* order ID, which is what I would expect.

Comment: @Alternative: Or you could change your method to accept 'int' for the searchOrder...

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok, thanks for that, retrieves the exact ID it's better. But my change doesn't works... I've the error, the value cannot be null for the line `int targetOrderId= Int32.Parse(searchOrder)`

Comment: @Alternative: change these lines: 'public ActionResult Search(string searchString, int searchOrder)' and 'user = user.Where(c => c.Order.OrderId == searchOrder);'

Comment: @Alternative: you need to change 'if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchOrder))' as well. Maybe to 'if (searchOrder > 0)'.

Comment: @mbm Thanks, it works. I needed to initialize my searchOrder to zero to avoid an error but it works.

Comment: @JonSkeet I do not understant this error. My method works now with mbm's answer but I like to know... Why in the case where I parse my string, I have this error " The value cannot be null".

Comment: @Alternative: Well it sounds like `searchOrder` is a null reference... that doesn't represent a number, does it?

Comment: In first place, searchOrder is a string, but when I parse it like you told me, it should be represent a number, no ?

Comment: @Alternative: Yes, it should. But if you're getting an exception of "The value cannot be null" then clearly it's a null reference. That's my point. You should only be trying to parse it if it's not null...